# Advanced bevel of a rounded corner

Tags: modeling, bevel

I've been racking my brain about this. I've been trying to model this relatively simple handrail but there is one part where I am just stuck. Here is the reference:

[image]
[image]

Now I sort of tried to bevel the corner of a cuboid. But I only get so far:

[image][image]

I kind of faked the desire result with a cylinder and a sphere, but I am sure there must be a more efficient way of getting there:

[image]

Grateful for any input! Thank you in advance!

Comment: or you can subdivide (smooth) 3 times a cube, keep only 1/4 and extrude

Comment: with a modifier?

Comment: or even simpler, bevel several edges

Answer (score 4):

Of course there is a simple way :)

1. Use Bevel modifier set to *Weight*, and with  Clamp Overlap
2. set Bevel Weight to 1 for selected edges.
3. It will result in some double vertices, you can use the *Weld modifier* to get rid of them.

[image]

Comment: Clamp Overlap totally did the trick! Thank you very much!

Comment: @JachymMichal  I don't think you did .. I suppose there is one more ... if you want all-quads, make sure the number of segments is even >:).. but that's just cheeky.

Comment: @RobinBetts That's a very good one! :)

Answer (score 0):

Just apply the scale of object, then bevel again.
To aply, go to object mode then select your object. Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> then select "scale" option.